# Employee present in all Services

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the tables

```
Employees
id
name 

Services
id
name

EmployeesServices
id_employee
id_service
```

I know if I make

```
select * from Employees inner join EmployeesServices on Employees.id = EmployessServices.Employee_id
```

EDIT: A `EmployeeServices` has many `Services` and `Employees`. I need to know if I have an `Employee` that is present at least one `EmployeeServices` of each `Services`

Sorry for the confusion, but it looks to be hard

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: At least have a bash at some SQL and tell us what is not working.

Comment: I know if I make

    `select * from Employees inner join EmployeesServices on Employees.id = EmployessServices.Employee_id`

I'll have the rows that match, but I need to know if i have someone employee that is present in ALL rows in `EmployeeServices`

Comment: You need to construct `SELECT` statement that finds all such employees. If it returns nothing - there are none.

Comment: Do you mean "an employee that is associated with all (distinct) services in `EmployeeServices`"?

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry, but now it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count distinct `id_service`s per `id_employee` in `EmployeesServices`:

```
SELECT
  id_employee,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) AS service_count
FROM
  EmployeesServices
GROUP BY
  id_employee
;
```

Now, you need to filter on the `service_count` value. Since that expression includes an aggregate function, you'll need to use a `HAVING` clause, because that's what is used to filter *row groups* (as opposed to individual rows, which what `WHERE` is for).

The condition, as I understand, should be "the number of distinct services per employee is the same as the number of services in the Services table". So, here we go:

```
SELECT
  id_employee,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) AS service_count
FROM
  EmployeesServices
GROUP BY
  id_employee
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Services)
;
```

Now, that will give you only the IDs of the employees matching the condition. Use the query as a derived table and join it to `Employee` to access the employees' details:

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  es.service_count
FROM
  Employee e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    id_employee,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) AS service_count
  FROM
    EmployeesServices
  GROUP BY
    id_employee
  HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT id_service) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Services)
) es
ON
  e.id = es.id_employee
;
```

Note that if `EmployeeServices` doesn't accept duplicate services per employee, you can replace `COUNT(DISTINCT id_service)` with `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain I understand what you're asking.  I'm not entirely certain you understand what you're asking, either, but that's not unusual when you're trying to come to grips with SQL queries.

Assuming that you have

- a primary key constraint on Services.id, and
- a primary key constraint on EmployeesServices(id_employee, id_service)

this should return all the employees who "have" every service. (Tested in PostgreSQL.)

```
select id_employee, count(id_employee)
from EmployeesServices
group by id_employee
having count(id_employee) = (select count(*) from Services)
```

There can't be duplicate rows in EmployeesServices. So the count of employee id numbers (grouped by employee id number) must match the count of services in order for an employee to "have" every one of the services.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return IDs of all employees that participate in all services:

```
SELECT es.id_employee 
FROM
(SELECT e.id as emp_id, s.id as serv_id FROM Employee e CROSS JOIN Service s) as full
LEFT JOIN EmployeeServices es ON es.id_employee=full.emp_id AND es.id_service=full.serv_id
GROUP BY full.emp_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(es.id_employee);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b327a/24) - you may want to experiment with the data

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table Employees (id number unique, name text);
    create table Services (Sid number unique, Sname text);
    create table EmployeesServices (EEid number, ESid number);
    insert into Employees values (1, 'bob');
    insert into Employees values (2, 'joan');
    insert into Employees values (3, 'philippe');
    insert into Services values (100, 'fell tree');
    insert into Services values (101, 'row boat');
    insert into Services values (102, 'read book');
    insert into Services values (103, 'sell book');
    insert into Services values (104, 'sell ticket');
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 100);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (2, 101);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (2, 101);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (3, 101);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (3, 103);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (3, 103);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (3, 104);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 100);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 101);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 102);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 102);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 102);
    insert into EmployeesServices values (1, 102);
    select count(*) as Number_of_Unique_Services_Available from Services;
    select id, name, count(distinct Sid) as Unique_Services_Performed
    from Employees, Services, EmployeesServices
    where id = EEid and Sid = ESid
    group by id
    order by Unique_Services_Performed desc, name;
```

I created some tables for testing. I assume that an Employee can perform the same Service more than once. The first select statement tells the number of unique Services available. The second creates output showing the number of unique Services performed by each Employee. Sample output below shows 5 unique Services and that no one performed all of them.

```
    Number_of_Unique_Services_Available
    -----------------------------------
    5

    id          name        Unique_Services_Performed
    ----------  ----------  -------------------------
    1           bob         3
    3           philippe    3
    2           joan        1
```